# Elasticsearch Javascript Browser Client

Tags: javascript, browser, elasticsearch

I am trying to run a query using browser client

http://jsfiddle.net/stnxx/27/

But i get

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './lib/client'e 
  @ elasticsearch.min.js:7(anonymous function) 
  @ elasticsearch.min.js:7d.19.vh 
  @ elasticsearch.min.js:10e 
  @ elasticsearch.min.js:7a 
  @ elasticsearch.min.js:7(anonymous function) 
  @ elasticsearch.min.js:7(anonymous function) 
  @ elasticsearch.min.js:20
(index):49 Uncaught ReferenceError: elasticsearch is not defined(anonymous function) 
  @ (index):49jQuery.event.dispatch 
  @ jquery-2.1.0.js:4371elemData.handle 
  @ jquery-2.1.0.js:4057
```

Am i missing anything ?

Javascript

```
client = elasticsearch.Client({
    host: 'Valid elasticsearch url'
})

client.search({
    body: {
        query: {
            match_all: {}
        }
    }
}).then(
  function (body) {
    $('#results').html(JSON.stringify(body.hits))
  },

  function (error) {
    $('#results').html(JSON.stringify(error))
  }
)
```

Comment: Did you figure this out? Is it because it needs to be loaded with browserify always?

Answer (score 0):

in your jsfiddle example yo have a syntax error in the query.

`query: { "range": { "date": { "gte":"20160318T00:00:00-0800", "lte":"20160318T23:59:59-0800" } } }`